# react - mockImplementation not working using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

App.tsx

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
...
export const App = () => {

  const rootNavigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<ParamList>>();
  const { params } =
    useRoute<RouteProp<ParamList, 'myScreen'>>();

  const navigateToHomePage = (): void => {
    if (params.isVerified) {
      rootNavigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [
          {
            name: 'HomePage',
          },
        ],
      });
    }
  };

  return (...)
}
```

App.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor, RenderAPI } from '@testing-library/react-native';

import { MigrationFlowContext } from 'src/contexts/migration/MigrationFlowContext';

import App from './App.tsx';

const mockedNavigate = jest.fn();
const mockedReset = jest.fn();

const mockSpy = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  params: {
    isVerified: true,
  },
}));

jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
  const actualNav = jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native');
  return {
    ...actualNav,
    useNavigation: () => ({
      navigate: mockedNavigate,
      reset: mockedReset,
    }),
    useRoute: async () => mockSpy(),
  };
});

describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockSpy.mockReset();
  });

  describe('isVerified = true', () => {...})

  describe('isVerified = false', () => {
    mockSpy.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        params: {
          isVerified: false,
        },
      };
    });
    test('Click Yes', async () => {
      const { getByTestId } = renderHomeScreen();
      ...
    });

    test('Click No', () => {
      const { getByTestId } = renderHomeScreen();
      ...
    });
  });

}
```

It didn't work with below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isVerified')
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Where have you defined mockUseRouteSpy? It does not appear anywhere else in the code besides in the mockImplementation. Did you mean to use mockSpy in the isVerified = false describe block?

Comment: Mocking hooks for an application is extremely unusual and considered bad testing practice.  You should be testing around the observable DOM or external dependencies like the history in the navigation context you need to provide, not the internal implementation details.

Comment: @possum then how am I supposed to test `useRoute<RouteProp<ParamList, 'myScreen'>>()`,?

Comment: By reading the documentation  or searching for examples?  The standard way to test things that are dependent on a context provider is to mock the context provided (like I said in my previous comment).  A memory router and asserting on  https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-memory-router and there's plenty of testing library tools and examples https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/